# IBM ServeRAID: how to use email alerts?

Tags: hardware-raid, system-monitoring

I just installed a brand old IBM server with a ServeRAID 4Lx card.
I installed the driver, and the ServeRAID manager software v9.30.
Everyting works as expected.

My problem is:
Yesterday, when not-so-randomly clicking here and there, I saw an email option in the ServeRAID manager software. It allow to configure a SMTP server, and emails addresses to send alerts.
Today I want to configure the email alert... and I don't find this damn parameter.
The documentation explain HOW to setup the SMTP, the addresses, etc, but not WHERE to find the parameters (the doc say this is in the "Actions" menu, but this isn't).

Anyone know where to find the email parameters into the ServeRAID manager software ?
I suspect I have to select a specific object in the window before the right option appear in the Actions menu.

**EDIT**: just to be clear: I already selected every object I found, and each time I checked into the "Actions" menu, and never found again the SMTP settings.
The documentation just mention I have to open the "Actions" menu and select "SMTP settings", but there is not such settings.
So I search a step by step method, or a clear way to find these settings. I know they exist because I saw them the day before I was ready to configure them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem several years ago. This was because the parameter *local only* was checked. I don't know why but this prevent the app to talk even with the local service.

Also check if the serveraid service is running because the app talk with it.

Once the app is connected with the service, you see the *configure* item in the icon bar. This is where you have the email settings.

Comment: Awww yes ! I had the "local only" checked too. I remember checked it then forgotten it, and I didn't realize this was linked. Now it is unchecked, I have every functions. Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you hear audible clicks and other sounds from the disks, you shouldn't wait for a failure to replace a bad component.

But for the IBM ServeRAID Manager software, the instructions are outlined here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eserver/v1r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdiricinfo%2Ffqy0_asmtpcfg.html

You have to select a valid object (controller, array set, etc.) before the Actions menu becomes selectable.

Comment: I don't think that he was saying his HDD was clicking, I think he meant that he was clicking (the mouse) around in the ServerRAID software and saw this option.

Comment: Gotcha. Tough week of questions...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want RAID notifications for ServeRAID, I gave up on the heavy application software and used my own script to do it.  Depending on the version of ServeRAID, you need to get the proper binaries from the package and then you can interrogate the status of the RAID array.  For ServeRAID 4Lx, I think it's ipssend.

I then used a simple script to send me notifications of *any* changes in status. e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

recipient="you@example.com"

/usr/local/bin/ipssend getconfig 1 > /tmp/raidstatus.now

# If there was a previous check, compare the previous output to this one
if [ -e /tmp/raidstatus.last ]
then
        diff /tmp/raidstatus.now /tmp/raidstatus.last > /dev/null
        err=$?
        if [ "$err" != "0" ]
        then
                /usr/bin/zip /tmp/raidstatus.zip /tmp/raidstatus.now /tmp/raidstatus.last
                /usr/bin/uuencode /tmp/raidstatus.zip raidstatus.zip | mail -s "RAID Message for `uname -n`" "$recipient"
                rm /tmp/raidstatus.zip
        fi
else
        mail -s "RAID Message for `uname -n`" "$recipient" << EOF

RAID monitoring has begun!

EOF

fi

mv -f /tmp/raidstatus.now /tmp/raidstatus.last
```

Answer (score 0):

Like ewwhite linked to, you have to select a valid object (and possibly provide admin credentials) before the choices appear.

In certain versions, when you choose the server object there will be a new toolbar with a Configure button, and there you can set it (gives you General, Notifications, Email Notifications, and Tasks).